# TextFormField is Empty after i add Map<String, dynamic> for static in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

getting error in **final Map<String, dynamic>? document;** in this part Widget textformfield is empty

```
class ViewTask extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewTask({super.key, this.document});
  final Map<String, dynamic>? document;

  @override
  State<ViewTask> createState() => _ViewTaskState();
}

class _ViewTaskState extends State<ViewTask> {
  late TextEditingController _titleController;
  TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
```

in this part the null safety error is occurs after i removing ??"title"

```
    String title = widget.document?["title"] ?? "title";
_titleController = TextEditingController(text: title);
  }
```

TextFormField widget part

```
  Widget title() {
    return Container(
      height: 55,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _titleController,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 17,
        ),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Task Title",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 17,
            ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you didn't update your ui after set that value, change your `initState` to this:

```
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    String title = widget.document?["title"] ?? "title";
    setState(() { // <=== add this
       _titleController = TextEditingController(text: title);
    }); 
}
```